# Bind data from a method to Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to display data from a list. Data in the list is updating inside a function. Actually I want to display the data only after execution of that function.

**Here is my template code.**

```
    <div class="modal-body">
          <td>{{shopName}}</td>
    </div>
```

**And this is my script.**

```
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "ViewShop",
      props:{
            shops:Object
        },
      data(){
        return{
          shopName:[],
        }
      },
      methods:{
        async shopd(sid){
          this.shopName=this.shops;
          console.log(this.shopName) // This prints the data in the console

        }
      }

    };
    </script>
```

I want to print the value of shopName in my template after executing the function `shopd()`

I think the `shopName` is accessed in template **before executing the function.** So what I need is **it should wait until the function make some changes** in `shopName` and then it should accessed to the template.

Comment: Generally this is why computed and watchers are for The question lacks clear problem statement and shopName  . It's unknown when and why shopName is changed and why it shouldn't be rendered. What should be rendered in the template instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the `shops` object as default value for `shopName` when rendering the component, since it's already a prop, you can simply call it in your `shopName` variable.

```js
      props:{
            shops:Object
        },
      data(){
        return{
          shopName: this.shops,
        }
      },
```

Then, if you want to update the `shopName` variable's value on the road, you're doing good assigning the new value with your `shopd` method, but you need a trigger event which is really what you'll be using for binding. For example:

```html
    <div class="modal-body">
          <td @click="shopd">{{shopName}}</td>
    </div>
```

which is equivalent to

```html
    <div class="modal-body">
          <td v-on:click="shopd">{{shopName}}</td>
    </div>
```

Last, if you just want to process the `shops` prop once before assigning the default `shopName` value, you can simply call the function in `shopName` variable and return the result

```js
      data(){
        return{
          shopName: this.shopd,
        }
      },
      methods: {
          shopd() {
              return this.shops
          }
      }
```